# Use part of external XSD schema in other schema

Tags: xsd

Lets say I have some external schema that defines a kind of envelope for web service:

```
<ext:envelope>
  <ext:message>
    <!-- anything else -->
  </ext:message>
</ext:envelope>
```

where ext is an external namespace
It defines `<ext:message>` as

```
<xs:any namespace="##any" processContents="lax" minOccurs="0"
            maxOccurs="unbounded" />
```

Here is my question: if I want to write WSDL schema for my service, that must comply to this envelope, how can I write schema which defines something like this:

```
<ext:envelope>
  <ext:message>
    <my:myElement />
  </ext:message>
</ext:envelope>
```

Should I somehow extend ext:message declaration? Is this kind of "extension" possible at all?

Answer (score 0):

There are many more constraints you have to consider. Let's contextualize this by first assuming XSD 1.0. In this case, the mechanism to maintain separation between the original XSD and your modified one is to use **xsd:redefine**. This allows composition of the XSDs, maintaining separation between the original source and your changes.

The prerequisite though is to have a global complex type declaration, or group, that defines the content model of the **ext:message**.

The xsd:redefine allows you to replace the wildcard with a content model of your choice. It would need to be a **restriction** of the type or group.

A redefine would give you an equivalent XSD that from an XSD spec perspective is just fine. However, from a tooling support, I would be surprised to hear of any XSD to code binding that supports xsd:redefine.

If, in your case, the tooling you use or target works with xsd:redefine, you're done. Otherwise, you may choose to apply an automatic XML Schema Refactoring, capable of creating an XSD file without the xsd:redefine. In effect, the automatic transformation does what you could otherwise do manually, except that it is a better choice for ongoing maintenance. The result XSDs (without the redefine) are virtually the same (since they represent the PSVI model) and could be used by your tools that don't support xsd:redefine.